# ways for white labelling in MAUI project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have project in Xamarin forms which we have to migrate to .NET MAUI we need White Labelling in that project like this [White Labeling in Xamarin Forms Applications](https://xamgirl.com/white-labeling-in-xamarin-forms-applications/)

e.g. in Xamarin.Forms I create configuration and define constant for that configuration in all projects (PCL, Android and iOS). then i give build action to info.plist and android manifest file that if at build time i choose any configuration it will pick that info.plist and android manifest file.

is there any way to do this?
if No what other ways i can white label my application.

I tried this exact method but in MAUI it is picking default info.plist and android manifest file.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you did? How can we reproduce what you're talking about? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: https://xamgirl.com/white-labeling-in-xamarin-forms-applications/

please refer this link. I did exactly same with info.plist and android manifest in maui but it is not picking right file in maui. ( in xamarin forms it is wroking as shown in this link.)
@JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: I downloaded the sample and tried to deploy it to my emulator, the result was that as soon as the app was launched, it crashed.

Comment: i am facing this issue with my project in windows. 
can we connect so i can show you on mac what i am doing and how it is woking in xamarin forms but not in maui. @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: I'm sorry, but we're only allowed to answer questions on the forum.